# Get vs Post Auto Mapping dates C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, automapper

I am having some confusion figuring out why I am experiencing the following:

If I using jquery `AJAX` to "post" some `Json` data containing a date to an MVC controller the automapper maps the date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` however if I use "get" instead the automapper seems to convert the date in to the format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Does anybody know why this would be the case? When I check the `json` payload and querystrings for the post and get respectively they are both in the same format. The date I am using goes across as "1/7/2013" in both cases.

Regards,
Gary

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a JSON serializer for the POST but a DateTime.Parse for the GET? This could yield two different results.

User [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to ensure consistent results. I.E.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
```

Comment: Hi I believe I am using the JSON serializer for both but it's a good place to start looking. I'm off work for another week so will check when I get back. Thanks.

Comment: Okay so there is a difference in culture between the GET and POST methods in the default model binder - check out this blog post for a detailed explanation: http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx